# When I am navigating from other screen my footer tab is hiding

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

When I am navigating from other screen to home screen then my footer tab is hiding .
I have to fic tis , my Bottom Tab Navigator should not hide if I navigate form any screen.
When screen reload then its hide , elase when I come back using back button its doesn't hide.

```
const AppNavigator = () => {
  const { colors, font, sizes } = useTheme();
  const { t } = useRtlContext();

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = HOME;
          } else if (route.name === 'Orders') {
            iconName = ORDERS;
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            iconName = PROFILE;
          }
          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return (
            <SvgCss
              xml={_.replace(iconName, new RegExp('{color}', 'g'), color)}
              width={wp('7%')}
              height={wp('7%')}
            />
          );
        },
        tabBarLabel: ({ tintColor, focused, item }) => {
          const color = focused ? colors.primary : colors.grey1;
          let labelName;

          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            labelName = t('home');
          } else if (route.name === 'Orders') {
            labelName = t('orders');
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            labelName = t('profile');
          }
          return (
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: font.regular,
                fontSize: hp('1.7%'),
                color,
                marginTop: 5,
                borderBottomWidth: 2,
                borderBottomColor: focused ? colors.primary : colors.white,
              }}>
              {labelName}
            </Text>
          );
        },
        tabBarStyle: {
          height: hp('7.5%'),
          paddingTop: hp('1.5%'),
          paddingBottom: hp('1%'),
          display: getTabBarVisibility(route) ? 'none' : 'flex',
        },
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.primary,
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: colors.grey1,
      })}
      initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Orders" component={OrderStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileStack} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Please suggest
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was using `props.navigation.navigate('screenName');`

Now changed to

`props.navigation.popToTop('screenName');`

and it is working fine.